# Is there any example of a sequentially-closed convex cone which is not closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

I am interested in showing that a sequentially-closed convex cone is closed in order to prove a representation theorem for a pre-ordered preference relation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you okay with my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the space $(\ell_\infty)^*$ endowed with the weak*-topology. The canonical image of $\ell_1$ in that space is sequentially closed by the Schur property of $\ell_1$, however it is also dense by [Goldstine's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem).